# Heat flux in the negative radial direction in a hollow cylinder

Tags: symmetry, thermal-conduction

Imagine a non-insulated pipe transporting steam at say 100°C. If outside the pipe, the bulk temperature is, again, say 25°C.
Then, due the temperature gradient a heat flux will be established across the thickness of the pipe, in the positive radial direction.
I understand that the flux will be decreasing because as $r$ increases, so does the area (heat flux = rate of heat transfer / area).

But now, if the situation is reversed: the surroundings are at 100°C and the pipe is now transporting water at 25°C. Also consider heat transfer in steady state. What would happen?

Will a given heat flux cross into the pipe in the negative radial direction?
Will this flux increase as the surface area is becoming smaller in the flux direction for this case?

Will the outer and inner surfaces of the pipe be somewhat... less than 100°C and more than 25°C, respectively?

I'm puzzled because when the heat flux is outward any cylinder, I can envision it "disappearing" as $r$ becomes infinitely large. But, if the situations I'm question for actually occur, would the flux leaving the inner surface of the cylinder sink at $r=0$?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the temperature outside is higher than inside, then the hear flux will be in the negative r direction:  $$\mathbf{q}=-k\frac{dT}{dr}\mathbf{i}_r$$And, since the total heat flow Q is constant within the wall, the heat flux will be increasing as r gets smaller:  $$Q_{inward}=-2\pi rk\frac{dT}{dr}$$or $$\mathbf{q}=-\frac{Q_{inward}}{2\pi r}\mathbf{i_r}$$
If there is convective heat transfer resistance between the outer wall and the outside medium and the flux is negative, then the outside wall temperature will be leas than the outside medium temperature.  Your conclusion for the inside wall and inside medium is correct also for the same type reason.

If the domain of the problem extends to r = 0, the boundary condition will be dT/dr = 0 unless there is a line sink at r = 0.